# JavaScript: Using property in method that not defined in constructor?

Tags: javascript

I saw this snippet of code below in [article](https://medium.com/swlh/lets-code-a-client-side-router-for-your-no-framework-spa-19da93105e10)

where the developer using property (`this.props`) in method ( `setProps`) that is not defined in the constructor.

```
class Route{
  constructor(name,path,view){
    this.name = name;
    this.path = path;
    this.view = view;
  }

  setProps(newProps){
    this.props = props;
  }

  renderVeiw(){
    return this.veiw(this.props);
  }
}

const newElement = new Route('foo','bar','baz')

console.log('fooo',newElement) 
console.log('fooo',newElement.setProps('hello'))
```

it's the first time for me to see this use case

- can anyone give me some explain?
- how to use it later because I tried to call the method with a random value but as I expected it will throw error

my question is about this pattern not the snippet itself so feel free to give me any other simple example if possible

---

Thanks

Comment: You can add properties to JS object any time anywhere.

Comment: *how to use it later because I tried to call the method with a random value but as I expected it will throw error* What do you mean by this? Can you give an example of what you did and what you were hoping it to accomplish?

Comment: "but as I expected it will throw error" --- it's not expected to throw, at least syntactically it's all ok

Comment: if so why he added it earlier like so ?

Comment: added what and where?

Comment: @zerkms sorry, you mean he referring to the property early  before adding it in new object

Comment: Where? But anyway, ask the author why they do it, there is nothing special in this code.

Comment: `this.foo = ...` in `setProps` does exactly the same as `this.foo = ...` inside `constructor`. Why would it throw an error in one and not in the other? (You may be thinking about languages were you need to rigidly define the fields of your class beforehand, but Javascript is not that.)

Comment: @deceze, if so why when I run the example above in browser consele  `console.log(newElement.setProps('hello'))`  throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code `this.props = props;`

```js
class Route{
  constructor(name,path,view){
    this.name = name;
    this.path = path;
    this.view = view;
  }

  setProps(newProps){
    // this.props = props; <- error here, should be 
    this.props = newProps;
  }

  renderVeiw(){
    return this.veiw(this.props); 
  }
}

const newElement = new Route('foo','bar','baz')

console.log('fooo',newElement) 
console.log('fooo',newElement.setProps('hello'))
```

Comment: While you're at it: *`veiw`*…